# Torch lua requires not finding the files

Tags: lua, torch

My directory structure looks like this:

--trian.lua

--util/

          -- misc.lua

          -- io.lua

          -- init.lua

In my train.lua I am using require to include the files in util directory as follows:

require 'util.misc'

require 'util.io'

require 'util.init'

When I execute train.lua, misc and io are loaded but init is not getting loaded. I am not sure how to debug this issue. Could some please help me with the issue?

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: @hjpotter92: From the main directory i am running  "th train.lua"

Comment: @hjpotter92: This works,   require 'util/init.lua' but not require 'util.init''

Comment: I figured out the issue. The name "util/init.lua" is a terrible idea. There exists a lua built-in library file with the same name and require doesn't load two files with the same name as described [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html)

Comment: also make sure the files you require are located in a folder listen in the package.path string.